# Prove that $\sum_{j=k}^{2k}(-1)^j\binom{n-j}{i}\binom{k}{j-k} =(-1)^k \binom{n-2k}{i-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove that
$$
\sum_{j=k}^{2k}(-1)^j\binom{n-j}{i}\binom{k}{j-k} = (-1)^k \binom{n-2k}{i-k}   
$$
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just fixed a typo, got it right now.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: my idea is to use induction, but it seems ugly, awkward. I'm trying to learn something new here.

Comment: The question will get closed without context / effort.

Comment: I see. This showed up in the middle of something I'm working on. I think I can prove it but the argument is mechanical,  so I'm looking for a neat idea here, in a friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

Seeking to evaluate

$$\sum_{j=k}^{2k} (-1)^j {n-j\choose q} {k\choose j-k}$$

we start with

$$(-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j {n-j-k\choose q} {k\choose j}
\\ = (-1)^k [z^q] (1+z)^{n-k}
\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j {k\choose j} (1+z)^{-j}   
\\ = (-1)^k [z^q] (1+z)^{n-k}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^k
\\ = (-1)^k [z^q] (1+z)^{n-2k} z^k
= (-1)^k {n-2k\choose q-k}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Neat. Thank you.